# Is it possible to find a matrix satisfying certain conditions?

Tags: matrices

In general, several (even not 'equivalent') matrices can have the same characteristic polynomial. Thus, it does not make sense to ask whether the process can be reversed, as there (seems to be) no unique algorithm to associate a matrix to a given characteristic polynomial.

However, given a characteristic polynomial (to be specific, $x^4-x^3-1$), is it possible to find *an* integer matrix such that both:

1. all entries are non-negative,

and

2. the sum of the integers in each column is the same?

Comment: Well, there **is** a *specific algorithm* to get a matrix having a given polynomial as its charac. polynomial. Google "companion matrix". It though doesn't generally fulfills your conditions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, it's not possible. If the sum of the integers in each column is the same (integer) $n,$ then the  vector $(1,1,1,1)^T$ is an eigenvector (not of $A$ but of $A^T$) with eigenvalue $n.$

However, the polynomial $x^4 - x^3 - 1$ does not have any integer roots.